# How many bytes is one character and how many characters make up 4096 bytes?

Tags: utf-8, character, byte

I was going through the Google my business API docs, which is a part of a project I'm working on,there it mentioned the maximum character limit is 4096 bytes,so I want the approximate count in characters limit for validation.

Comment: Can you please clarify which part of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding need clarification for you to find the answer?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I couldnt find it in this reference,can you please help me,getting it that how many characters make up a bytes

Answer (score 3):

In [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), 1 *Unicode codepoint* is encoded in 1..4 *bytes* depending on its assigned value. 1 visual *character* (grapheme) could be made up of *multiple codepoints*.

In ASCII-only text, all characters take up 1 byte, so 4096 bytes can hold 4096 characters.

In Latin-based text, characters can take up 1..2 bytes, so it would be *close* to 4096 characters (as most ASCII characters are used, with occasional accents), but could be as low as 2048 characters.

In Eastern Asian charsets, or even just with Emojis, etc, they make use of higher valued codepoints that frequently need to be encoded in 3..4 bytes per codepoint, so much fewer characters would be used.

So, to answer your question, "how many characters fit in 4096 bytes", the answer is "it depends on the text".  UTF byte encodings are *variable-length*.

Comment: And which char encoding method is used in the WEB?

Comment: @Aashiqahmed everything I said applies to the Web, to Email, to chat services, etc. Byte encodings are independent of the transports, protocols, containers, etc that use them.